# EF6 - No connection string named 'Data Source=...' could be found in the application config file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to set a connection string dynamically to the MyDataContext inheriting DbContext and I got this error:

> No connection string named 'Data Source=myserver\mine;Initial Catalog=MyDb;User ID=user1;Password=mypassword;Connect Timeout=300' could be found in the application config file.

Here's what my code look like:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext, IDataContext, IDataContextAsync
    {
    private readonly Guid _instanceId;

    public DataContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        _instanceId = Guid.NewGuid();
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

//and so on...
}

public class MyDataContext : DataContext
{
        public MyDataContext (string nameOrConnectionString)
            :base(nameOrConnectionString)
        {
        }
}
```

I'm wondering why this is happening. As what I've understand, the constructor can accept either connection string name and connection string. In this case Entity Framework seem to expect a name.

Please help.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want [`DbContext(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) and not [`DataContext(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350721%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) given the EF tag (and you referencing `nameOrConnectionString` argument).

```
public class MyDataContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDataContext(String nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

Otherwise the `DataContext` is looking for a file source, which could be the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Sorry. I updated my post to make it more clear. Actually, MyDataContext is inheriting DataContext that is inheriting DbContext. DataContext, IDataContext and IDataContextAsync are not from EntityFramework. They're custom classes.

Comment: Not too sure then. EF basically detects if it's a name or a connection string by the presence of '=' sign. But, I can say you're failing somewhere in [here](https://gist.github.com/bchristie/9256686).

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the connections string to the `.config` file in the MVC project (i.e main project) and make sure that MVC project as a startup.